# Why do nodejs exec/spawn not show any output for bash 'history' command?

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, shell, exec

I am running this on Ubuntu and have tried many variations of exec/spawn functions (and their sync counterparts) and none of them can show me an output for bash 'history' command. One scenario is following:

```
const { spawnSync} = require('child_process');
const child = spawnSync('history', { shell: "/bin/bash" });

console.log('error: ', child.error);
console.log('stdout: ', child.stdout.toString());
console.log('stderr: ', child.stderr);
```

It does not show any errors and output is empty. I think this question has more to do with 'specialty' or category of the history command than nodejs's function since they work fine for normal commands like ls, pwd, whoami, etc work fine. I have looked at my .bash_history file and its filled with history so that's not the issue.

Another problem that might be similar is `ll` command also fails even though I have set bash as shell. But for `ll`, it does return an error:

> /bin/bash: ll: command not found

Just to be sure, I tried running `ll` command in bash it worked just fine. What am I missing here?

edit: I have done some more testing it seems more like a bash thing than a node thing. When I simply write the `history` command, bash prints results but when I do `bash -c history`, it does not show any output but also no error.

[image: image of bash output].

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to messages from child process

```
 child.on('error', (err) => {
 });

 child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
 });

 child.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
 });
```

Comment: Same result as my own code. I also subscribed to stdout in addition to your code but that result is never printed for history command. Other commands are printing their result just fine. Could it be a bash thing instead of node?